# Finding a vertex to complete a parallelogram in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and finding a cosine between two vectors.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Trying to solve an exercise regarding vectorial geometry, I have two doubts:

> For $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}^3$,
>
> $$A = (0,1,0)\\ B = (2,2,0) \\ C = (0,0,2) \\ D = (a,b,c)$$
>
> First, determine the values $a,b,c$ so that the figure ABCD is a parallelogram.

To determine $D$ algebraically, I'm not so sure. However, if I draw the 3D shape, it seems to me like it must be

$$D = (2,1,2)$$

Simply visually. However it concerns me that I fail to do this algebraically - what should I do to do so?

---

> Then, calculate the cosine of the parallelogram ABCD's angle, whose vertex
>   is the point $B$.

I have a formula written here,

$$\cos o = \frac{\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}}{||\vec{u}|| \cdot ||\vec{v}||}$$

So, if the vertex is $B$, it means that the two vectors to use with this formula should be the ones that are connected to it in the parallelogram, which are $A$ (because it is at the same $z$ level as $B$) and... $D$, because it has the same $x$ coordinate as $B$, I think.

So basically

$$\frac{A\cdot D}{||A|| \cdot ||D||}$$

$$\frac{(0,1,0)\cdot (2,1,2)}{||(0,1,0)|| \cdot ||(2,1,2)||}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{0^2 + 1^2 + 0^2} \cdot \sqrt{2^2 + 1^2 + 2^2}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1} \cdot \sqrt{9}}$$

$$\frac{1}{3}$$

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Use $AD||BC$. This turns it into a single variable. You also know its length as $AD=BC$...

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the point $D$, take a look at a regular paralelogram with vertices

```
D      C

A      B
```

The point $B$, for example, can be calculated by taking the point $A$ and *adding* the vector $\vec{AB}$. In the same way, the point $D$ can be calculated by adding the vector $\vec{BC}$  to the point $A$.